# How to use DataTable in jqwidgets datasource

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqwidget

I have a Data stored in DataTable in code behind, How to use that datatabe to bind in JQWidgets.
Please provide if any link available for refrence

```
        DataTable tb=new DataTable();
        tb = rp.GetRelaasePlan();   // Datatable
```

This need to used in front end jqxgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fully a Client Side Grid So,

First you have to convert `Datatable` to `json` data, Using `json` data you can pass the values to `jqxgrid`

1.For converting DataTable to Json try this [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19396/Convert-ASP-NET-DataTable-to-JSON-to-use-a-DataTab)

2.For assigning json values to gird try this [LINK](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?(arctic))